# How to properly use .itemconfigure() in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to remove the underline from the items in my list box when i select it. I tried giving the entire list box the "activestyle=None" but i learned that you need to use the "itemconfigure". What i am lost on is what i should be putting for index. I have my .insert index as 'end' and it works properly but when i do that for the item configure it says its out of range. Here is the code if anyone can assist me here.

```
taskList = Listbox(setBox, bg="#1B2834",fg="white")
taskList.configure(width=183,height=39, activestyle=None, fg="#4299E9", selectbackground="#061523", 
selectforeground="#4299E9")
taskList.itemconfigure('end', activestyle=None)
taskList.insert('end', taskIDnum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `itemconfigure` to set the `activestyle` attribute. You should use the `configure` method of the listbox. The documented value to turn off the ring around active item (or underline, depending on platform) is the string `"none"`, not the python value `None`.

```
taskList.configure(activestyle="none")
```